# Showing 0 after decimal separator in java

Tags: java, android

i'm doing a calculator app and i'm using Decimal Format to format my number.
My problem is i want it to show number like 0,003. But 2 zero after the comma didn't show up until I typing 3. Please help me fix this
Here my code

```
DecimalFormatSymbols formatSymbolsGermany = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###.########", formatSymbolsGermany);
```

My code to add "0"

```
private void zeroOnClick() {
    if (tvNumber.getText().toString().length() < 11) {
        convertNumber("0");
    }
}
private void convertNumber(String number) {
        number1 += number;
        try {
            double a = Double.parseDouble(number1.replace(',', '.'));
            tvNumber.setText(decimalFormat.format(a));
            delete = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
private void addComma(){
    if (comma) {
        //do nothing
    } else {
            number1 += ",";
            tvNumber.setText(number1);
            comma = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to just `tvNumber.setText(number1);` directly without the back-and-forth conversion while editing and display it in the proper format only after the editing is done.

Another possibility would be to artificially append a digit before the conversion if the number contains a decimal point and then remove it afterwards.

```
String res = number1.replace(',', '.'); // shouldn't this be decimalFormat dependent ?
if( number1.contains(".") ) {
    res = decimalFormat.format( Double.parseDouble(res+"5"));
    res = res.substring(0,res.length()-1);
} else {
    res = decimalFormat.format( Double.parseDouble(res) );
}
```

Comment: Hi. I don't think it cause by tvNumber.setText. Because when I typing number like 0,3201. Number 0 didn't show up until I typing number 1

Comment: setText itself does not have anything to do with this. It is how decimalFormat.format converts the number. if you typed 0,320 the double value will be just 0.32 and so will the decimalFormat.format output it. So if you artificially add for example "5" at the end, the double value will be  0.3205, the format will output 0.3205 and if you clip the last character you will get what you want, 0.320